# Rotating rectifier waveform

Tags: synchronous-motor

I am testing a circuit which is used in a synchronous motor rotor excitation.

[image]

I am testing the part when the rotor is stationary and the motor stator has a rotating magnetic field, in that case it will be inducing an AC voltage and this test is basically to test that behaviour.

So I connected a single phase AC supply at F1 F2 and got the below waveform on the scope.

[image]

So far so good the diodes are working and only the positive half cycle is visible on the scope.

On increasing the voltage from the variac the SCR is turned on I suppose and then I was expecting to see the other half of the AC wave, but I am getting the below waveform on scope

I don't understand where the diode half cycle part gone.

[image]

The scope is connected here:

[image]

Comment: .... and what is the scope connected to?

Comment: Half of the input waveform is short circuited by the three-phase bridge.

Comment: How that occurs?

Comment: Well, look at the diodes.

Answer (score 0):

As the voltage is increased the Zener diodes begin to fire the SCRs to short out the positive side of the AC waveform.